# How can I open lsp-find-references using split-window-vertically?

Tags: window, lsp

I have new windows be opened in a split-window-horizontally way, but I want this specific lsp-find-references to be opened with split-window-vertically.

Is there any way to set this preference for this command?

..or, is there a way to call this function, telling it to open in the same window?

I have the same issue with M-x compile, as I want the compilation buffer to be on the vertical split.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 0):

You should check the manual before asking this type of question (and search for duplicate questions, of course). See [chapter 21.6 Displaying a Buffer in a Window](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Displaying-Buffers.html) of the Emacs manual. In particular, [subsection 21.6.1 How ‘display-buffer’ works](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Window-Choice.html) tells you how to customize the behavior of `display-buffer`, which commands such as `lsp-find-references` and `compile` all use, in various ways.

Most importantly for you, you can customize the behavior by modifying `display-buffer-alist` to have an appropriate action function (such as `display-buffer-below-selected` perhaps) for buffers of a given name (such as `"*Compile*"` or whatever `lsp-find-references` uses).