# lsp-mode open declaration / definition in other window

Tags: lsp-mode

I'm starting to feel a bit frustrated: this should be as simple as setting some variable or other, but I'm unable to find which one.

Say I'm editing file `foo.c` and I find something like

```
void foo(int n) {
  bar(2 * n);
}
```

I put the cursor on `bar` and hit `s-l g g`. The resulting call to `lsp-find-function` correctly finds the file `bar.c`, containing the definition of `bar`, and displays it. But it does it **in the window previously holding** `foo.c`.

I suppose there is some configuration option allowing one to say: "please, open the file you find in another window" but I'm unable to find it and I run out of queries to throw at google for that :)

Note that I did find [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/78144/how-can-i-open-lsp-find-references-using-split-window-vertically), but the answer there doesn't help me, because introducing rules matching `*.c` in `display-buffer-alist` doesn't strike me as a smart thing to do.

Help is worth at least a coffe or a beer next time you happen to be in Rome

Comment: Does `lsp-mode` use `xref` under the bonnet for this stuff? Maybe there is a variable or a hook for `xref`? `xref--show-xrefs` is this what creates the actual display?

Comment: As far as I can understand the code, yes. I followed the call starting from `lsp-find-definition` and I end up with `xref--show-xrefs`. The display-action parameter to the latter comes from the `:display-action` argument given to `lsp-find-definition` (which I suppose should be `nil`, because `lsp-find-function` is called interactively and `interactive` in its definition has no argument)

Answer (score 2):

You’ve already found the solution in the comments, but I’ll go ahead and spell out how you can use it:

```lisp
(defun thehobbit-lsp-find-definition ()
  (interactive)
  (lsp-find-definition :display-action 'window))
(keymap-global-set "C-c ." 'thehobbit-lsp-find-definition)
```

This just adds a different key binding, one which calls `lsp-find-definition` with a different `:display-action` argument.

You could also do something similar with advice if you prefer not to change the key bindings.

You should also consider the `xref-show-definitions-function` variable, which controls what happens when there are multiple definitions to choose from.

Comment: Yea, needed to check the args for `xref-show-xrefs-function`, I stopped one short of that :).

Comment: I'll look into the advice idea, as there are a lot of `lsp-find-*` functions, all of them built using `lsp-find-locations` with different parameters. Thank you

Comment: Yes, that’s another good reason to use advice.